# JavaScript onClick update Div

Tags: javascript, html

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vhw8xewy/5/)

I am trying to update a few div's with new text every time a button is clicked. I have tried many things it seems that the function isn't even being called. When I put what I want it to do directly in the onClick event it works. It just doesn't work when I call a method.

It works when I do this.

```
<button onClick="document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = 'Some Title'">Click me</button>
```

But when I try to do this.

```
<button onClick="update(0);">Click me</button>
```

It doesn't work.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: use event listeners .. we are in 2015 ... jc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the JavaScript is running before the HTML has finished loading.

Change the Fiddle to run the JavaScript in the body.

In the drop-down on the left of the Fiddle where is says `onLoad` - change this to `No wrap - in <body>`.

Your code will work as is.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/vhw8xewy/8/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
onClick="(function(){document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = 'Some Title'})()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in your JS just define the "update" function instead of declaring it as a function.  Check out this fiddle where it works: https://jsfiddle.net/vhw8xewy/6/

```
update = function() {
   ...
}
```

instead of

```
function update() {
   ...
}
```